# What URLs on an https page need to be https?

Tags: html, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I did a search and could not find an answer on here to my question. What I am confused about is what URLs on an `https` page need to be `https`, as opposed to `http`.

I am making a series of pages my website that must be accessed over `https`. At the top of the pages is a menu. I accidentally included a style sheet into the page using `http`, instead of `https`, and all the browsers I tried gave me a warning about insecure content. But, I can leave the menu links at the top of the page `http`, and there's no problem.

So, am I correct in saying that things that are being *loaded* onto the page, such as style sheets and images, need to have `https` in the link, but that plain old `href` links can just have `http` in them?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: ALL urls for loading external content (imgs, scripts, etc...) need to be https. You cannot load non-secure data into a secure page without getting warnings/errors. You can have links pointing at non-secur epages, but there'll still be "you are leaving a secure page" warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally your secure pages such as *purchase* page, *credit card* etc processing pages are set to `https` or sometimes all pages such as websites for *banks or other financial institutes* or even *login* pages.

You can leave it to browser to deciper `http` or `https` part by using what is called **protocol-relative URLS** in which you simply do not specify either of `http` or `https` and still browser will be able to figure it out. An example:

```
//example.com
//google.com
```

Let's say your domain is `foo.com`, you would specify all URLs like:

```
//foo.com/page1.html
//foo.com/otherpage
```

So you simply leave the `http` or `https` part in your URLs.

To know more about protocol-relative URLS, see:

- http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all links that are used to create the page itself (the HTML, the CSS, JavaScript, the images) need to be served over `https`. That means all URLs of that domain need to be served over `https`.

Links to other websites can be `http` just fine. You may want to check if those links can be visited over `https` as well because then the user will use a secure connection to visit those website as well.

Comment: But if I make the menu links `https`, then the same problem will happen once they click that link (they'll get to another page being served over `https`, which creates the same problem). I only want these few pages being served securely.

Comment: @Nate: That is unavoidable as the user is leaving a secure page. But why not serve those pages over `https` as well? You can take away "some parts of this web page are not secure" messages by serving all content over `https` but if you leave a secure page, browsers can indeed inform the user about this.

Comment: Simeon, from what I've read, it is very inefficient to serve an entire website over `https`.